# Typescript: find type in an array of objects

Tags: typescript

The title might be a little confusing but I have no idea how to explain it better.
I have a set of hard coded classes from a 3rd Party library (I cannot change them). The content of those does not matter, it is just to explain the situation

```
class Parent {}
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}
```

Now I have a function to do something with those classes

```
const doSomething = <T extends Parent>(someClass: T, options: SomeOptions<T>) => {}


doSomeThing(new Child1(), {foo: 'bar'});
doSomeThing(new Child2(), {id: 1});
```

depending on the class I pass, I have a set of different options that are required. I would like to create interfaces for those options in order to autocomplete them. Usually I would like to do it like this

```
interface SomeOptions {
    Child1: {foo: string},
    Child2: {id: number},
}
```

however this does not work as I cannot use Classes as an index type, so I guess I have to do it like this

```
type SomeOptions = [
    {class: Child1, options: {foo: string}},
    {class: Child2, options: {id: number}},
]
```

But with this scenario: how can I grab the correct options based on a class?
Something like

```
const doSomething = <T extends Parent>(someClass: T, options: FindMeTheCorrectOption<T>) => {}
```

My goal is the following

```
doSomeThing(new Child1(), {foo: 'bar'}); // okay
doSomeThing(new Child2(), {id: 1}); // okay

doSomeThing(new Child2(), {foo: 1}); // TS error, foo must be string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried on the playground and here is the result.
Put `someClass` as `Parent` allow the input to be any class that extends from `Parent` and options will accept right type of `SomeOptions`

```
interface SomeOptions {
  Child1: { foo: string };
  Child2: { id: number };
}
class Parent {}
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}
const doSomeThing = <T extends keyof SomeOptions>(
  someClass: Parent,
  options: SomeOptions[T]
) => {};
doSomeThing(new Child1(), {foo: 'bar'}); // okay
doSomeThing(new Child2(), {id: 1}); // okay

doSomeThing(new Child2(), {foo: 1}); // TS error, foo must be string
```

Comment: doh - thank you really much. Not sure why I wasn't able to figure this out. Thank you